# What is induced matching, maximum induced matching and mim-width?

Tags: graphs

I understand the concept of *induced subgraph*, but could not understan what *induced matching* is. As appears in [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000010001285) paper, it is defined as

> A matching in a graph is an induced matching if it occurs as an
>   induced subgraph of the graph.

However, in [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X05002633) paper, there is a slightly different definition:

> A matching in a graph is a set of edges, no two of which meet a common
>   vertex. An induced matching M in a graph G is a matching where no two
>   edges of M   are joined by an edge of G.

Thus, I am confused since there are no example figures.

Also, there is a term called *mim-width*, which is maximum induced matching width and few no none examples exist in the literature.

Could you please give some examples for me to clear things out?

Answer (score 4):

Both definitions are the same. An *induced matching* $M$ in $G$ consists of a set of edges such that $G|_{V(M)} = M$, that is, the subgraph of $G$ induced by the vertices of $M$ is exactly $M$. This is the first definition.

Now it is always the case that $G|_{V(M)} \supseteq M$, so $M$ is an induced matching if $G|_{V(M)}$ contains no other matching, that is, $G$ contains no edge connecting vertices in two different edges of $M$. This is exactly the second definition.

I have never heard of *mim-width*, so it is safe to assume that it will be defined in any paper which uses it. However, it probably refers to the size (probably number of edges) of the largest induced matching in the graph.

Comment: is this the same with independent edge cover?

Comment: I have no idea what independent edge cover is, but I bet it is defined in any paper that uses this concept.

Comment: Induced matching requires the edges to be isolated (i.e. no common vertices, i.e. matching.)

Comment: Mim-width. For a graph G and a vertex subset A of G, we define mimG(A) to be the maximum size of an induced matching in G[A, V (G) \ A]. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.05157.pdf